# generalized eigenvalues of graph laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a weighted undirected graph of $n$ nodes. Let $W$ be the weight matrix of $G$ and $D$ be a diagonal weight matrix (the entries are row/column sums of ). Let $L:=D-W$, the Laplacian (basically $L$ is a diagonally dominant matrix). I read from a paper that there are $n$ generalized eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $L$ given as follow:

$$Lf_k=\lambda_k Df_k, k=0,1,2,\dots n-1$$

with $0=\lambda_0\le\lambda_1\le\dots \le \lambda_{n-1}.$ (I know why $0=\lambda_0$)

I wonder how to prove the existence of $n$ nonnegative generalized eigenvalues.

Comment: Is $L$ necessarily symmetric?  That is, are the weights the same in both directions along every edge?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I should assume that. Thanks

Comment: In that case: it is well known that a diagonally-dominant symmetric matrix with positive values on the diagonal will be positive semidefinite.  That is, it will have $n$ (possibly repeating) non-negative eigenvalues and an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but I am asking about the generalized eigenvalue , as defined above. There is a matrix D before f.

Comment: Ah I didn't understand that you were giving a definition of "generalized eigenvalue" for this context, now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that we have no zero-rows, so that $D$ is invertible. Note that
$$
Lx = \lambda Dx \iff\\
D^{-1/2}Lx = \lambda D^{1/2}x \iff\\
(D^{-1/2}LD^{-1/2})(D^{1/2}x) = \lambda (D^{1/2}x)
$$
That is: the generalized eigenvectors of $L$ correspond to the (standard) eigenvectors of $M = D^{-1/2}LD^{-1/2}$.  Because $M$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite, it must have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.  Correspondingly, $L$ has $n$ linearly independent generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Thanks... math brain teaser...